# java.io.FileNotFoundException in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I'm new here to learn Spark and Scala using the Notebook and Cluster in [Databricks.com](http://community.cloud.databricks.com/), here is my very simple code to load a file:

```
import sys.process._
val localpath="file:/tmp/myfile.json"
dbutils.fs.mkdirs("dbfs:/datasets/")
dbutils.fs.cp(localpath, "dbfs:/datasets/")
```

but I got error like this:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/tmp/myfile.json does not exist.
>
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:402)
>
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:255)
>
> at com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtils$.cp(DBUtilsCore.scala:82)
>
> at com.databricks.dbutils_v1.impl.DbfsUtilsImpl.cp(DbfsUtilsImpl.scala:40)

I'm using Mac and I've made sure that the file exists in this absolute path, is this a spark error? Thanks!

Comment: Databricks.com doesn't run on your host, so I'm not sure it can access your local files. See https://forums.databricks.com/questions/828/how-do-i-import-a-local-csv-into-databricks-cloud.html

Comment: Yes you're right, it should be in the dbfs of Spark but not in my host

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
val localpath="file:/tmp/myfile.json"
```

should be:

val localpath="file://tmp/myfile.json"

Basically all URIs are of the format ://path see [RFC-3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)